# Call direct route without hash from Backbone

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

I'm probably tackling this the wrong way but bear with me:

**in my server.js I got this**

```
tweetThisThing = require('./lib/kustomtwitter'),

app.get('/tweet/:msg', function(req, res){
var tweet = req.params.msg;
tweetThisThing(tweet); // le magic
    res.redirect('/cars');
});
```

When I direct my browser to  `http://localhost:3000/tweet/This will be tweeted` a tweet is successfully being sent out.

When I try to invoke the same express endpoint through Backbone like so:

**In my Backbone script I got this**

```
app.navigate('tweet/' + theMessageThatWillBeTweeted,  {trigger:true, replace: true});
```

, Backbone always forces a hash in the route and then fails to send the tweet `http://localhost:3000/#tweet/This will not be tweeted`

I know this is expected behaviour and some "workarounds" involve adding **pushState:true** to my Backbone script, but I don't seem to be able to get it working.

Is there an easy way to get the behaviour I want or do I need to setup a backbone route for this specific usecase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If turning on [pushState](http://backbonejs.org/#History-start) with

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
```

doesn't work an alternative is to bypass Backbone all together and just use [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). For example:

```
$.get('tweet/' + theMessageThatWillBeTweeted, function(result) {
   // Also instead of redirecting you could output the twitter response code
   // and verify the request was a success here
   console.log(result);
});
```

By the way, using `GET` probably isn't the best way to do this. You'd probably be better off using `POST` which would give you much more flexibility and cleaner urls.

Comment: Thanks for your kind intervention.
Really wanted the Backbone way to work , but I can't make it happen, so I appreciate the alternative.